# Filter Array (with nested Objects) by dynamic props

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of N objects. I would like to write a filter that filters using JSON.stringify based on multiple and dynamic properties.

But dynamic without static properties (like the code above)
Do you have any ideas?

```
return items.filter(item =>
    JSON.stringify(item.prop1 && item.prop2 && ....)
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchParam)
);
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you provide some example data and what you expect to filter form it...

Comment: You're saying you want to have a list of properties that are included in the object before you `JSON.stringify` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna have to write a function that transforms your object into a stripped down object with just the properties you want:

```
function getProperties(obj, propList) {
  var newObj = {};
  propList.forEach(prop => {
    newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

And then your code will look like this:

```
var propList = ['id','name','date']; // just for example, put whatever properties you want in here
return items.filter(item =>
    JSON.stringify(getProperties(item, propList))
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchParam)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 items.filter(item => ["prop1", "prop2"].some(key => item[key].toLowerCase() === searchParam))
```

Using `JSON.stringify` to turn the object into a searchable string is a bad idea as the keys are also included in the search and it will be way slower than just traversing the neeeed keys.